# mvc5 create select from select

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

this is the table:

```
id subject number type
1  1       12     1
2  1       13     1
3  1       14     1

4  1       3      2
5  1       12     2
6  1       14     2
```

need result of

```
subject   sum-number   type
1         39            1
1         29            2
```

how to query this with lambda expression in mvc 5

Comment: do you need sql.?

Comment: why do you need a lambda expression specifically ? what benefit is there ?

Comment: here is simple, but in complex query i need to print the summary of the large result which i have already prepare in lambda with mvc 5

Comment: ok fine sql also no problem i will change it

Answer (score 1):

only SQL

```
select subject, sum(number), type
from table
group by subject, type
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL query like

```
    select subject, sum(number), type from table group by type, subject
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use below LINQ query:

```
var result = context.tableName.GroupBy(x => x.type).Select(x => new { subject = x.First().subject , sum-number = x.Sum(y => y.number) });
```